# How to check the server load

Tags: apache

I want to check the server load before push the files to live. Is any way to check server have capacity to handled the concurrency users. Also we have checked the ab in terminal side but need to check without files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/server-status` handler ([mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html)) to check that.

Configuring it is fairly easy and straighforward:

```
<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require host example.com
</Location>
```